# Is there a way get original foreground object colors foreground substraction?

Tags: opencv, background-subtraction

I am using BackgroundSubtractorMOG2() to extract foreground of video.I am wondering about "how to get original colors of the image and set it foreground".I want to extract objects with original colors not threshold.

Foreground Extraction Code:

```
let video = document.getElementById('videoInput');
let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);

let frame = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
let fgmask = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC1);
let fgbg = new cv.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(500, 16, true);

    const FPS = 30;
    function processVideo() {
        try {
            if (!streaming) {
                // clean and stop.
                frame.delete(); fgmask.delete(); fgbg.delete();
                return;
            }
            let begin = Date.now();
            // start processing.
            cap.read(frame);
            fgbg.apply(frame, fgmask);
            cv.imshow('canvasOutput', fgmask);
            // schedule the next one.
            let delay = 1000/FPS - (Date.now() - begin);
            setTimeout(processVideo, delay);
        } catch (err) {
            utils.printError(err);
        }
    };

    // schedule the first one.
    setTimeout(processVideo, 0);
```

Original image

[image: Original image]

My output

[image: My output]

I want this

[image: I want this]

Comment: you'll have to fill the gaps so that the foreground mask is white everywhere where you want to get the color. Then originalImage.copyTo(dst, mask)

Comment: Thank you.originalImage.copyTo(dst, mask) work very well.How can i fill the gaps?                                                                                                       
Input: https://streamable.com/k8d3r Output:: https://streamable.com/dmra7